# wordpress sending value from template to function.php

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I have this theme that modifying for my own purpose & kinda stuck in this problem.
 I wanted to send a value from template html to `function.php` which contain all my calculation of prices etc.

```
<select name="menu1" id="menu1">
 <option value="1">Microsoft</option>
 <option value="2">Google</option>
 <option value="3">Apple</option>
 </select>
```

how to make `menu1` known to `function.php`

Comment: you can do this using ajax please see my answer http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/247602/90674 it should help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### in file functions.php

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts' );

```
function my_scripts(){


        wp_enqueue_script('my-script',__DIR__.'/some-my-script.js', array('jquery'), false, true);

        wp_localize_script('my-script', 'myajax', 
                array(
                    'url' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php')
                )
            );

}
```

### in file 'some-my-script.js'

jQuery(document).ready(function($){

```
$('#menu1').on('change', function(){

        jQuery.ajax({
          method: "POST",
          url: adv_aj.url,
          data: { 
                    action: "some_func_php",
                    my_value: $(this).val()
            }
        })
      .done(function( msg ) {
            console.log( msg );
      });

});
```

});

### in file functions.php

add_action('wp_ajax_some_func_php', 'some_func_php'); // if its request from admin
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_some_func_php', 'some_func_php'); // if its request from front

function some_func_php(){

```
$my_value = $_POST['my_value'];

update_option('name_option', $my_value );

wp_die();
```

}